# How to install sage on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, sagemath

I have installed Ubuntu Desktop 14.04.1(32bit) LTS. I want to install sage on it. But I can not able to install sage. I know that Oracle VirtualBox can do it. I don't want to do so. Any one can help me to install sage.

Here is the linkfor sage: http://ftp.iitm.ac.in/sage/linux/32bit/index.html

For Ubuntu 14.04(32bit), sage is not available. Please help.

Comment: What is unclear from the readme on that page? http://ftp.iitm.ac.in/sage/linux/32bit/README.txt "The file sage-x.y.z-i686-Linux.*, which you download here,
contains **a pre-built version of SAGE that can be decompressed
into a directory and run from there.**" So download, extract, run should be all there is to it.

Comment: They don't build specifically for each new version, but the file should run on any newer version. Try it.

Answer (score 1):

Install via [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~aims/+archive/ubuntu/sagemath):

```
apt-add-repository -y ppa:aims/sagemath
apt-get update
apt-get install sagemath-upstream-binary
```

Comment: I don't know how the `-s moved there.